# MySQL - how to join a Company OR Person table to a Contact table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `Contact` that represents a real-life contact - so has a name, address, phone number, etc. - that could be either a Person or a Company. They obviously have a different attributes, like a person has a date of birth for example.

How do I structure this in a database?

I tried it like this.. `Contact` has fields `id`, `displayName`, `numViews`, `type` and `entityId` (fk), and added two more tables to represent a `Person` and a `Company`. So if the contact is a Person then `type = 'Person'` and `entityId` matches the person's id in its table. I couldn't figure out how to select all contacts with an upcoming birthday though. Note: I know the sql for upcoming birthday - so I can do this on the Person table - it's the joining I'm stuck on. I seem to need to join on a table where the name of the table is in my `type` column!

Am I overlooking something simple? Perhaps I have the structure wrong?

Comment: Why not have `contactID` as a field in your `Person` and `Company` tables instead of having `type` and `entityId` in your `Contact` table?

Comment: Maybe my brain isn't functioning today.. how would I get the entity - either `Person` or `Company` - when I'm looping through my `Contact`s?

Comment: Personally, I think you're coming at it the wrong way. You should (in my opinion) really be starting with either the `Person` OR `Company` table, and then looking from there to the `Contact` table. Chances are you're not wanting to mix the two (correct me if I'm wrong). I it should be as simple as something like `SELECT * FROM Person p JOIN Contact c ON p.contactID = c.id WHERE [your WHERE clause here];`

Comment: Unfortunately I will be mixing the two. On the main page I list most visited contacts - which can be either Person or Company - and also any contacts with upcoming birthdays - which would only be people. Either way when you click the contact's name it should log that they've been viewed and display their details - which would be different details whether they're a person or a company.

Comment: I have this working but today realised I overlooked that a Contact can be either a Person or a Company.

Comment: Expanding on Patrick's point, my own view is that you start with the organisation. In a business context, everybody belongs to (at least one) organisation - even if that organisation is just a 'project_client_group' or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current table structure, something like this will work:

```
Select
<whatever fields>
FROM Person 
INNER JOIN Contact
   ON Contact.type = 'Person' 
  AND Contact.entityId = Person.id
```

Assuming you have a birthDate field in Person, you can also put in a where clause similar to this:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(Person.birthdate, NOW()) BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Unfortunately it is just the first part of this I got stuck on. Now how would I list all contacts - which are either a Person or Company - and display, for example, their phone number? For showing one contact I would be happy to get the Contact's info, store them in my PHP object, then run a second sql query to get their details from table `$contact->type` and matching on `$contact->entityId`; but when looping through all Contacts that seems inefficient.

Comment: So, you're starting from the Contact, figuring out whether the contact is a Person or a company and showing appropriate information?

Select 
<whatever fields>  
FROM Contact
LEFT JOIN Person 
ON Person.id = Contact.id 
AND Contact.type = 'Person'
LEFT JOIN Company 
ON Company.id = Contact.id 
AND Contact.type = 'Company'

<where statements>

Comment: You are correct, but unfortunately your code is not. `Person` and `Company` are linked via `entityId` not `id`. As both a `Person` and a `Company` can have an id of 1, for example, then your query returns both the `Person` and `Company` records. Where it should only return the record of id 1 from the table that matches `Contact.type `.

Comment: I think you actually have answered the main question anyway, and this question about advance joining for effeciency is probably best posted on Code Review.